# How to Cancel Scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I use UIScrollView to make large-sized (larger than 320px) UI on iPhone.

I made an instance of UIScrollView and added some subviews on it.
The problem is that I want to enable scrolling only when user touches outside of subviews,
stop scrolling when user touches one of subviews.

I read documents and tried to find samples but I can't find good hint.
If you have any idea, please help me.

Comment: @Chris Hanson: Why did you remove iPhone and UIScrollView from the tags? Those are the correct tags - cocoa-touch can be added, but should not stand alone here.

Comment: I didn't remove or edit those tags :(

Comment: Because back when I made that edit, polluting the tag space with names of classes and redundant information wasn't a good idea. It still isn't, I just gave up on fixing that crap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to detect touches inside any of the subviews of the UIScrollView, you will have to subclass UIScrollView and override the `touchesShouldBegin` and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` methods which are specifically created for this purpose.

Other than this, there is no way you can identify touches in the subviews as UIScrollView tends to handle all touches itself and doesn't pass them to its subviews.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to override touchesShouldBegin / touchesShouldCancel... methods but these methods were never called.
Maybe something is wrong with my coding but I can stop scrolling by overriding touchesBegin/touchesMoved/touchedEnded methods.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you doing this in a subclass on UIScrollView? The methods will be called only then. So instead of your UIViewController using a UIView as its view it should use a subclass of UIScrollView as the view

Comment: Yes, i tried this in a subclass of UIScrollView. I got some problem in my implement(only overriding touchesBegan...), so I keep trying to find the reason why touchesShouldBegin method was never called.

Comment: I had the same problem. For me, it was due to the underlying subview (UIImageView) not having the userInteractionEnabled set to YES.

Comment: This answer is wrong, shouldn't be the accepted answer. You DO NOT have to subclass UIScrollView at all. There is a bug in UIScrollView that breaks UIViews - if you fix your UIView's, all touches work perfectly (they drop through to the UIViewController) AND the scrollview continues working as expected. The secret is to set nextResponder correctly in the UIView subclass when Apple accidentally deletes it

Answer (score 36):

UIScrollView has a *scrollEnabled* property that allows you to disable scrolling programatically. It also has a delegate (UIScrollViewDelegate) that allows you to see events such as scrolling starting/ending. Seems that you should be able to cook something up with those options combined in some way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will try your solution now.

Comment: Nice answer, vague but enough to get started. +1

Answer (score 8):

The property you're really interested in -- and I'm actually testing this out right now, because I have the same problem you do -- is `canCancelContentTouches`.

> If the value of this property is NO,
>   the scroll view does not scroll
>   regardless of finger movement once the
>   content view starts tracking.

If this doesn't give you the results you want, subclass UIScrollView and override the `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView` method, which is what the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this is set `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` for the scrollview. That way the default behavior is set so that anything which is a UIControl will pass the touches on to the control immediately and everything else will scroll.

Comment: If this is set to NO the behavior is the opposite of what the OP wants. If this is set to YES, it's not much better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also sublcass UIScrollViewController and override the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded methods. If your implementation never calls the superclass implementation, then it won't scroll.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried your suggestion and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was having a view that a user could draw in but the scroll view was hijacking the touch and scrolling instead of drawing. This is my working solution:

In my drawing view I have:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Disable scroll on touch begin
    setContainerScrollingEnabled(false)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    // Reenable scroll on touch end
    setContainerScrollingEnabled(true)
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}

private func setContainerScrollingEnabled(_ enabled: Bool) {

    // loop up superviews to find the scrollview
    func scrollingSuperview(of view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
        guard let superview = view.superview else { return nil }
        if let scrolling = view.superview as? UIScrollView { return scrolling }
        return scrollingSuperview(of: superview)
    }

    // and switch on/off scrolling
    let scrollView = scrollingSuperview(of: self)
    scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = enabled
}
```

and in the view controller containing the scroll view I have:

```
// Not sure what exactly this does, but I think it allows the drawing view to have precedence. This was the missing piece of the puzzle.
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Comment: This worked for me. By the way, you may want to enabled scrolling on touchesCancelled, too!