# whatsapp share is not working (same code is working in another project)

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, whatsapp

Below is what I am using to share text on WhatsApp

```
NSString *globalString;

NSString *myURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebq8.com/mobile/newsdetails.aspx?id=%@", [global getstrProDetails]];

globalString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ للمزيد  \n\n%@",[global getstrPagetitle], myURl];

NSLog(@"globalString===%@", globalString);

NSString * msg = globalString;
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", msg ];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
    UIAlertView *mAl = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your device doesn't have WhatsApp." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [mAl show];
}
```

Below is the output I have of NSLog.

```
حاول الانتحار فألقى بنفسه بين أسود.. وخرج حياً للمزيد  

http://www.mywebq8.com/mobile/newsdetails.aspx?id=22455
```

When I click WhatsApp icon, its opening WhatsApp but message is not showing in showing... It is just showing blank.

Any idea why this is working?

***Note: Same code is working is another project of mine which is updated on 09 May 2016.***

---

### Edit 1

Even if I try below still its not working

```
This is test text

http://www.mywebq8.com/mobile/newsdetails.aspx?id=22455
```

Comment: your code is correct there is issue with your message NSString *myURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebq8.com/mobile/newsdetails.aspx?id=22455"];
   
    globalString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"بين أسود.. وخرج حياً للمزيد للمزيد  \n\n%@", myURl];                                                                                                if you send NSString * msg=@"hello stackflow"; it is working fine so check with your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution . The problem is with the URL encoding.
Please find my tested solution below

```
NSString *globalString;

NSString *myURl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebq8.com/mobile/newsdetails.aspx?id=%@", [global getstrProDetails]];

myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
myURl = [myURl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

globalString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ للمزيد  \n\n",[global getstrPagetitle]];

NSLog(@"globalString===%@", globalString);

NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@", globalString ];
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],myURl];

NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:msg]];
} else {
    UIAlertView *mAl = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your device doesn't have WhatsApp." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [mAl show];
}
```

Hope this Helps!.

let me know if you find any difficulty.

Comment: Might be the url coming in that code is something different.

Comment: This is saying `Your device doesn't have WhatsApp.`

Comment: `NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];` should be `NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:msg];`??

Comment: yes actually we encoded the text separately and encoded url separately both with different ways, and then combined  both of them .
R u facing any difficulty ?

Comment: but `whatsappURL` don't have url in it... so how it will go to watsapp?

Comment: I meant text that will be displayed in watsapp will have have my news details link...

Comment: Oh yes. Correct . Mistakenly written . :)
Corrected now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112618/discussion-between-saurabh-goyal-and-fahim-parkar).