# How to cancel scrolling when subview is touched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a scrollview with some subviews as tiles. The scrollview has its "Delays content touches" and "Cancellable Content Touches" set to YES.
I capture touches in each subview with `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesMoved`.

When you tap a button and almost immediatly start to scroll, the button highlights and the scrollview do not scroll, without any code needed.

When I do **exactly the same thing without changing anything**, touching the view but outside the button, these touch methods are triggered, but the scrollview scrolls.

What may I do in those touch methods to cancel the scrolling when a touch is done outside the button to have the same behaviour that prevent the scrollview to scroll ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this adding this code in touchesBegan and touchesEnded when touch is catched by the subview.

```
UIView* superView = self.view.superview;
while (superView != nil) {
    if ([superView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        UIScrollView* superScroll = (UIScrollView*)superView;
        superScroll.scrollEnabled = YES/NO; // put the right value depending on the touch method you are in
    }

    superView = superView.superview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect touches inside any of the subviews of the UIScrollView, you will have to subclass UIScrollView and override the touchesShouldBegin and touchesShouldCancelInContentView methods which are specifically created for this purpose.

Other than this, there is no way you can identify touches in the subviews as UIScrollView tends to handle all touches itself and doesn't pass them to its subviews.

Courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/392562/1865424

If you have any further issue regarding this.Happy to help you.

Comment: That is not correct because I do not do anything special with my UIScrollView, and even on deactivating the Gestures I could have added, I can cath the touches in my subviews. The problem is that when they are catched, there is still a short moment where the UIScollView continues to handle the scroll as opposed as what happens when a sub-UIButton is touched.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, maybe you can add:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressDetect = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(disableScrolling:)];

[subView addGestureRecognizer:longPressDetect];
```

and then add a method that disable and re-enable the scrollView from scrolling such as:

```
-(void)disableScrolling:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)longPress {

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is just a trick, that is not needed for the UIButton as shown in my example. I just want to do with my touchable UIView what is done by the UIButton to prevent the scroll.