# UIScrollView overrides my subview's pan gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

If I have a scrollView with a subview and the subview has a pan gesture recognizer, the scrollView's pan gesture override's the subview's pan. What I want is the opposite, I think, so that is I drag a subview it will pan within the scroll view, yet if I touch another area the scroll view will pan as normal. Is there an easy way to set that up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what works for me:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *subviewPanRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panSubview:)];
[subview addGestureRecognizer:subviewPanRecognizer];

// play nice with subview's pan gesture
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer 
    requireGestureRecognizerToFail:subviewPanRecognizer];
```

Comment: That seems to be the default behaviour (that's what I'm observing in practice in a UIScrollView with a UIImageView subview). Could someone confirm/infirm?

Comment: Works beautifully, especially when applying a delegate on the subview and implementing `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`.

Answer (score 1):

Set `canCancelContentTouches` property of `UIScrollView` to `false` if you don't want to scroll on touching subviews.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3810011/2764966)

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite these two delegate below,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
```

}

This will allow you to recognize both gestures, the default return is NO, so we need to overwrite it and return **YES**.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
    if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}
return YES;
```

}

In this delegate you can do anything as you wish, as it's name  the **gestureRecoginzer** will be required to fail by the **otherGestureRecognizer**, all you need to do is to judge what kind of these two gestures and return YES or NO.